# C# Protobuf: Default instance of message fields instead of null?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

In c++ and python versions of protobuf generation, for example let's see the following:

```
message Sub {
  optional int int_val = 1;
}
message Root {
  optional int int_val = 1;
  optional Sub sub_val = 2;
}
```

In python you'd be able to simply do something like

```
my_proto = Root()
print(my_proto.sub.int_val)
```

and in C++ similarly

```
Root my_proto;
std::cout << my_proto.sub_val().int_val();
```

However in C#, this would return a null reference error

```
Root myProto = new Root();
Console.WriteLine(myProto.sub_val.int_val);
```

**My question is**, is there a way to make protoc generator have default instance instead of null for C#? Or a way to access the field and set default if not set and return without much code overhead?

I've tried initializing all the necessary sub fields to avoid null reference but this does not scale with more complicated protobufs. I've tried searching around for possible options to generate but doesn't seem to be an option that allows such things.

Similarly in https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/csharptutorial/ there is only option to initialize with all data at once. Even looking into the generated C# code, it seems we can't avoid null reference at least with the options I used since they don't specifically generate a new instance of the object for a field not set.

Comment: You could use reflection to iterate across a generated class and create fields / sub messages as you discover them. Though I recommend taking care with this; if you create an object and then set all optional fields / sub messages to reference appropriately created default objects, you'll then have to unset them later if it turns out that you'd not amended them to contain useful values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused; why would it be desirable to have a default instance? The item here is optional, and it is *required* that optional values can be omitted, and it is *expected* that they are omitted by default. It is also *expected* that you can tell the difference between a present and absent sub-message, which is achieved here via a `null` test. Nice and simple, and idiomatic .NET

It seems to me that the C# version is doing the correct thing?

If you *want* an instance:

```cs
var obj = new Root {
    sub_val = new(),
};
```

(assumes up-to-date C#, otherwise you'll need to specify the type in the `new`)

Comment: I see. The main issue I was facing was if I ended up having a complicated protobuf.

For example if I have 10 message fields under a proto and each of those message fields also have let's say 2 or 3 subfields.

Then in order to work with this protobuf, I need to instantiate one by one to avoid coming across null reference.

This was somewhat of a behavior I am more used to in python and C++ where referencing those values don't need a specific null check.

I think I can live with this being more of a c# feature and make sure the instantiation of the protobuf is done better. Thanks!